# I need to prove...( Show that the σ-algebra generated by the intervals of the form (a, b) is also the Borel σ-algebra, that is: σ{(a, b) ⊆ R : a ≤ b}

Tags: measure-theory

I´m having trouble with this demostration. I need to prove that the sigma algebra generated by the intervals (a,b) in R is the same as the sigma algebra generated by the intervals (-∞,x] in R.
I tried to prove it using this preposition.Proposition. Let C1 and C2 be two collections of subsets of Ω such
that C1 ⊆ C2. Then σ(C1) ⊆ σ(C2).
So if I can prove that C1 ⊆ C2 and C2 ⊆ C1, then the demostration is done.

Comment: Let $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ be the two $\sigma$ fields. Since $(a,b) = (-\infty, a]^c \setminus (\cap_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, b+{1 \over n}])$, we see that $(a,b) \in \Sigma_2$ and so $\Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma_2$. Since $(-\infty,b] = (\cup_{n=1}^\infty (b,b+n] )^c$, we see that $\Sigma_2 \subset \Sigma_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1=\{(-\infty,x]\vert x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Consider $(-\infty,x]$ in $C_1$. You can show that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n)= (-\infty,x]$ where $b_n\searrow x$ and $a_n \to -\infty$. Therefore, we can prove that $C_1 \subseteq \sigma(C_2)$, and as a result  $\sigma(C_1) \subseteq \sigma(C_2)$.

In the other direction for consider $(a,b) \in C_2$. Then, consider $(-\infty,x_n)$ and $(-\infty,y_n)$ where $x_n \nearrow b$ and $y_n \searrow a$. Then, $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,x_n]=(\infty,b)$ and $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,y_n]=(-\infty,a]$, and $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,x_n] /\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\infty,y_n]=(a,b)$. Therefore, you can show that $\sigma(C_2)\subseteq \sigma(C_1)$.

Comment: Thank you. But what does this synbol / mean?

Comment: subtraction of sets

Comment: Thank you bro. I´m an economics student from South america. I did not found that notacion on an spanish math book. We use another symbol for subtraction.

Comment: If you need any clarification please let me know.